# cordova-plugin-screen-orientation not working on specific pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to allow both orientations on one view only but the rest of my other 10 views should be locked in portrait. I don't mind doing this tediously by setting each of my 10 views' controllers to lock on portrait. But I can't seem to get the screen-orientation plugin to work.

I used the CLI to install the plugin (succesfully installed)

and then this is the code

config.xml:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="default"/>
```

Controller: (this does not work)

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $ionicPlatform) {

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I couldn't comment earlier due to insufficient rep at the time, but could you please post your environment/configuration details?

Comment: I am going to be posting a screen capture video of exactly what is happening...but basically I setup buttons with the function to change orientation...when I click the landscape button it quickly switches to landscape and then back to portrait...so it works but just for a millisecond lol

Comment: Google Drive link to video:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-UHZL-BFMtYmRUbTRRUHBXcVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried testing on a physical device?

Comment: I haven't...I am having trouble connecting my device to xcode ('error: Could not find Developer Disk Image') ...do you think a trying on a physical device would make a difference?

Comment: 3 hours later...xcode and el capitain upgraded...and still exact same problem but now on my device :(

Answer (score 1):

You should check if Cordova is loaded first.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
}
```

Or since you're using Ionic:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
});
```

(For the latter, be sure to inject the $ionicPlatform dependency.)

Comment: Still not working...i added my config.xml code if that helps

Comment: Per this [thread](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/issues/67), it seems that the plugin js file needs to be included in your index.html file for it to work.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/www/screenorientation.js"></script>`

Comment: That doesn't work either...I think there are issues with <cordova 4

Comment: I have the same problem, suddenly stopped working. Non of those solutions work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and it will work as expected

```
screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial. It helped me with the same problem:
https://topherpedersen.blog/2019/09/26/cordova-screen-orientation-lock-plugin-not-working/

```
// Lock Device Orientation
function lockDeviceOrientationCallback() {
    // set to either landscape
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
    console.log("locking device orientation...");
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", lockDeviceOrientationCallback, false);
```

The solution is similar to the above answer of setting an event listener when the device is ready.  I found this one worked better because cordova already have a device ready listener and i could seem to piggy back on it.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I put it in Interval and it's worked:

```js
let ticks = setInterval((timer),10);
function timer() {
    function lockDeviceOrientationCallback() {
        // set to either landscape
        screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
        console.log("locking device orientation...");
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", lockDeviceOrientationCallback, false);
}
```